# Let's get critical: Aug 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://cs.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Easy infinite subclass of cubic graphs for Hamiltonian cycle problem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/28286/easy-infinite-subclass-of-cubic-graphs-for-hamiltonian-cycle-problem)

**Net Score: 12** (Excellent: 14, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Find missing value in period of LCG](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/28197/find-missing-value-in-period-of-lcg)

**Net Score: 11** (Excellent: 15, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Finding number not in list with wildcards](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/27822/finding-number-not-in-list-with-wildcards)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [What's the value of this game (rebalancing counters)?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/27777/whats-the-value-of-this-game-rebalancing-counters)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 11, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Existence of Efficient Set Difference Algorithm](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/27570/existence-of-efficient-set-difference-algorithm)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 12, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 8)

---

- [Why Do Computers Use the Binary Number System (0,1)?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/27656/why-do-computers-use-the-binary-number-system-0-1)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 6)

---

- [Monotone boolean satisfiability with at most k 1s is NP-Complete](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/28274/monotone-boolean-satisfiability-with-at-most-k-1s-is-np-complete)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [How does the OS know the physical address of a process' first memory page?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/28284/how-does-the-os-know-the-physical-address-of-a-process-first-memory-page)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 13, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [What is the state of the art in efficient boolean function operations?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/27964/what-is-the-state-of-the-art-in-efficient-boolean-function-operations)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 12, Needs Improvement: 7)

---

- [Computer science for programmers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/28051/computer-science-for-programmers)

**Net Score: -6** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 14, Needs Improvement: 8)

---

Comment: so "Net Score" = "Excellent" - "Needs Improvement"

Answer (score 3):

Thanks. I see a bunch of scores. Have not the faintest idea what I should learn from this.

Comment: Positive score means more of the people who participated in the review thought the question was "excellent" than "needs improvement". I guess it's meant to measure how satisfied the community is with itself.