# Examples of how to use the site evaluation to improve the site?

Tags: discussion, support, site-evaluation

We just completed our Aug 2014 site evaluation: [Let's get critical: Aug 2014 Site Self-Evaluation](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/902/lets-get-critical-aug-2014-site-self-evaluation).  It looks like every question got between 20 and 25 votes one way or another.

Most of the voters agree that some of the questions/answers are "excellent" and some of the questions/answers "need improvement."

Now what?  Presumably the Stack Exchange staff thinks that this exercise can, somehow, be used to improve the site quality over the long term.  But how?

**What are the examples, from this site or others, of how this data can be used to form actionable plans to improve the site?**

Comment: For reference, [this was not the first evaluation](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-evaluation) and depending on our position in the graduation queue, it may not be the last. As I understand it, these evaluation are mostly a means to get a quick indicator of average site quality; a "mostly good" result means "continue", a "mostly bad" result would mean "change something".

Comment: The only (maybe) relevant post on [meta.SE] I could find is [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115988/strategies-for-handling-beta-community-quality-evaluations). (I did not read most of it.)

Comment: @AnnaLear's answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161033/which-questions-need-community-evaluaton) may also be relevant.  According to that answer SE staff are trying to get information about how well each beta community is [search-engine optimizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) itself.  Seems like an extremely poorly designed way to get information about search-engine optimization.  Better to ask us directly (a) which search terms bring up the question as a top hit and (b) whether we are happy that we're the top hit for that query.

Comment: Definitely, even though it's hard to make use of that information, either. Which queries we did not try lead to us? Are there inverse Google queries? (I don't think I have actually googled for a question, ever; I just evaluate what I see. Whoops.)

Comment: I think [Google webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools) is the closest thing to "inverse queries".  It's only accessible to the site's administrator. (I.e., someone on stack exchange staff.)